# Why is Android Studio build taking too long if app is uninstalled from device/emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.1

I am building my app in Android Studio, and whenever I'm making changes, I hit debug (Ctrl+D) and it launches in a matter of seconds, which is great.

However, when I uninstall my app from the device, and hit build again (no project-cleaning or anything) it takes about a minute for the project to build. It seems that Android Studio is building the whole project again from scratch. Why is this happening *even if I didn't change a single line of code*? The APK is the same, all Android Studio needs to do is to push the APK again to the device/emulator.

This is getting extremely annoying when I'm trying to test new user UX/login flow as I'm deleting the app each time from the device repeatedly. Am I missing something, or is there a solution?

Comment: Which version of Android Studio and Gradle you are using?@Can Poyrazoğlu

Comment: Instead of uninstalling, you may try to clear the app data.

Comment: @CrazyAndroid 2.1 beta3 (but I'm almost pretty sure that it's the case with non-beta too)

Comment: Did you got an option to upgrade your gradle?@Can Poyrazoglu

Comment: @CrazyAndroid I tried the new experimental gradle (I think it was an experimental build with major changes) but it broke so many things (especially with NDK compilation which I'm using in my project) so I had to revert to the whatever version is supported with my IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to your gradle.properties. That help you a little to reduce you gradle build !

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.daemon=true
```

Comment: Yeah, just like @sha unfortunately nothing has changed after adding these lines. Build still takes the same length after removing the app.